# Optimizing nested ifelse in shiny

Tags: r, optimization, shiny, nested-if

This post is not much of a cry for help as my script works exactly as intended, but I was wondering if there was maybe a better way to write it given that it's quite heavy, I may need to make changes in the future and I've started a personal project for which the method I used here would probably be way too time-consuming and less practical (as the personal project is even bigger...)

Basically, I'm making an app to help my coworked choose the best statistic test for their analysis.

the UI looks like this :

```
    ui <- fixedPage(
  titlePanel("Choisir son test statistique"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,selectInput("choix","Que voulez-vous faire ?", c('a1',
                                                              'b1',
                                                              'c1',
                                                              'd1'))),
    column(3,conditionalPanel(
      condition="input.choix=='stat'",
      selectInput("type","Quel type d'analyse ?", c('a2',
                                                    "b2",
                                                    "c2",
                                                    "d2")))),
    column(3,conditionalPanel(
      condition="input.choix=='d1'&&input.type=='b2'||input.choix=='d1'&&input.type=='c2'",
      selectInput("groupe","Combien de groupes ?", c('a3',
                                                     "b3",
                                                     "c3",
                                                     "d3"))),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.type=='Lien entre Variable'",
        selectInput("variable","Quel type de variables ?", c('a4',
                                                             "b4",
                                                             "c4",
                                                             "d4")))),
    column(3, conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.choix=='d1'&&input.type=='b2'||input.choix=='d1'&&input.type=='c2'",
      selectInput("indep", "Indépendance des données ?",c('a5',
                                                          "b5",
                                                          "c5"))),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.choix=='d1'&&input.type=='b2'||input.choix=='d1'&&input.type=='c2'",
        selectInput("param", "Normalité des données ?",c('a6',
                                                         "b6",
                                                         "c6",
                                                         "d6")))),
    
    mainPanel(htmlOutput("texte"))))
```

My "problem" starts with the server part that I wrote with a LOT of nested if_else. I'm a complete newb when it comes to shiny so this was really the only way I knew how to tackle it. Let's have a quick look :

```
server <- function(input, output) {   output$texte <- renderText({ 
    if(input$choix=="a1"){
      paste(analyse_desc)}
    else{if(input$choix=="b1" ){
      paste(shapiro, levene, bartlett)}
      else{if(input$choix=="c1"){
        groupe<-input$groupe
        param<-input$param
        indep<-input$indep
        type<-input$type
        if(input$param=="d6"){
          paste(shapiro, levene, bartlett)}
        else{if(input$groupe=="b3" &&
                input$param=="b6" && 
                input$type=="b2"){
          paste(student1)}
          else{if(input$groupe=="c3" &&
                  input$param=="b6" && 
                  input$indep=="b5"&&
                  input$type=="b2"){
            paste(student2, welch)}
            else{if(input$groupe=="d3" &&
                    input$param=="b6" &&  
                    input$indep=="b5"&&
                    input$type=="b2"){
              paste(anova1)}
              else{if(input$groupe=="b3" &&
                      input$param=="c6" && 
                      input$type=="b2"){
                paste(wilcoxon1)}
                else{if(.........)}
```

I won't put the entire script, you've got the general idea : I need to implement an ifelse for every possible choice from the user and there is like 20 of them.

Just that is already huge (for me at least) and my other project might need even more.

I've seen something about case_when() but when I tried to use it, I couldn't put several of them in a row (or maybe I just didn't do it properly, I don't know).

So basically my question is : do any of you guys would know if there are a more optimized way of doing those kind of nested ifelse (which would make it easier to implement changes later) or if it's just brute strenght all the way ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Thats a lot of ifelses... With that many conditions it seems as if you need a different approach. I would try to have all the conditions stored neatly in a dataframe, and then retrieve the answer from there, as it would make more evident the underlying logic. But if you still want to go the if else route, then try nesting all conditions inside the more general conditions, for example, `if groupe == "d3"`, and then add all the other conditions that happen only when the first general condition is met. That way you have some semblance of structure.

Comment: Thanks Bastian ! I'm not quite sure I can see what you mean by storying the conditions in a dataframe though (code wise I mean). For you other solution, do you mean something like 

`if groupe == "d3{ "
     if param =="d4"{
          if indep == "b2"{}}}
  else if groupe =="d4".....`

something like that ?

Comment: I just mean creating a dataframe with all inputs as columns (type of analysis, type of variable, independence, normality, etc.) and then a column for methods that satisfy those conditions. I will answer in your question to give you an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to have all the conditions stored neatly in a dataframe, and then retrieve the answer from there, as it would make more evident the underlying logic. You could create a simple dataframe with all conditions as columns (type of analysis, type of variable, independence, normality, etc.) and then a column for methods that satisfy those conditions. Then you could just filter that dataframe in order to get the possible methods.

```
methods <- tribble(~group, ~type_variable, ~independence, ~normality, ~method,
                   "a",    "numeric",      FALSE,         TRUE,       "method1",
                   "a",    "numeric",      TRUE,          TRUE,       "method2",
                   "a",    "numeric",      TRUE,          FALSE,      "method3",
                   "b",    "factor",       FALSE,         TRUE,       "method1",
                   "b",    "logical",      FALSE,         TRUE,       "method2",
)

# A tibble: 5 × 5
#  type_analysis type_variable independence normality method 
#  <chr>         <chr>         <lgl>        <lgl>     <chr>  
#1 a             numeric       FALSE        TRUE      method1
#2 a             numeric       TRUE         TRUE      method2
#3 a             numeric       TRUE         FALSE     method3
#4 b             factor        FALSE        TRUE      method1
#5 b             logical       FALSE        TRUE      method2

methods |> 
  filter(group == input$group,
         type_variable == input$type_variable) |>
  pull(method)
```

Comment: Thank you Bastian ! I was able to make it work with a couple conditions, I will try with a full dataframe and see how it goes. My only issue is that the "method" I need to pull is usually a full paragraph of text (I need to explain how the method works, what are the tricks and things to be aware of) but it doesn't seem possible with pull(), it makes the app freeze

Comment: Problem solved by creating a list with the text for each methods as variable, putting the name in the dataframe, pulling it with the script you gave ma and calling the corresponding variable in the list

Comment: Nice to hear that! Great idea.